# Does a digital torque adapter requires calibration?

Tags: tools, torque, wrench

I've been looking to buy a digital torque adapter to use with my wrench, as an alternative to a click torque wrench.

I know that click torque wrenches requires calibration after ~1000 clicks or one year since last calibration. I've been trying to find information about if a digital torque adapter requires calibration and how often, but I had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they do.

Annually at least, and the good ones are sold with calibration certificates from new.

Comment: Are you talking about digital torque wrench or digital torque adapter? I can't find any information about calibrating a digital torque adapter.

Comment: Any device doing that type of task gets calibrated especially in a production environment - called quality control...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how accurate you want it to be. Every measuring instrument is regularly calibrated  for a serious quality assurance program . I expect there are QA books on the subject. On the otherhand for a home garage ,as answered, once a year is enough if it is regularly used ; and the first calibration sound be when it is new.